# uiautomator takescreenshot not work for no reason

Tags: android, ui-automation

I tried to take a screenshot in the internal storage during automation testing,but when run the test,it didn't show any error,but when I check the file,the screenshot didn't take successfully,I am so confused right now,please help me~

Here is part of my code:

I have my permission in my AndroidManifest.xml already

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS "/>
```

screenshot

```
UiDevice mDevice =UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
mDevice.pressHome(); 
mDevice.takeScreenshot(new File("/sdcard/Pictures/test.png"));
sleep(3000);
```

I am sure the direction is not wrong cause I tried the same code before,it worked normally,but after few days I tired it again and it failed without showing any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try

mDevice.takeScreenshot(new File("/sdcard/Download/test.png"));
sleep(3000);

Comment: I tried and it didn't work,maybe the problem is not the direction I guess?

Comment: @abcde581125 capturing screenshot via adb shell command, that works?

Comment: ,thanks for your advice, I know this ,but now I need to do is to take screenshot automatically,that's why I use this way to take screenshot,can I capture screenshot via adb shell command automatically?

Comment: yes...try using uiDevice.executeShellCommand("command");   Also remember to exclude "adb shell" string from the command itself...if its not working...tell me about the command, I'll try it here and share exact code with you